# Can we update a fetch a record and update the Primary key attribute in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

Let's say we have a DynamoDB record with Primary Key: A1 and GSI (Hash Key: B1 and RangeKey: C1).

And we have the following records in the database:

```
A1        B1        C1
--------------------------
value1    value2    value3
value4    value5    value6
```

Now, I want to query a record with Primary Key A1 with value `value1` and update the same A1 attribute to `value7`.

If we can do this, what is the impact on other partitions. Will we run into any issues if we do it like this?

Does this have any impact on the table? Given we operate at a large scale.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by this "And we have the following records: A1 B1 C1 value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6". Are "A1 B1 C1" keys or values?

Comment: @jellycsc I have updated the question

Comment: Thanks, another clarification, what kind of impact on the table are you asking?

Comment: If we can do this, what is the impact on other partitions. Will we run into any issues if we do it like this?

Comment: Of course not, I personally don't see any reason or major impact on why you can't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this.

> You cannot use UpdateItem to update any primary key attributes.
> Instead, you will need to delete the item, and then use PutItem to
> create a new item with new attributes.

From: [Amazon DynamoDB API Reference AttributeValueUpdate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValueUpdate.html)

By creating new item, obviously there will be no tragic implications.